# how to copy all the URLs of a certain column of a web page?

Tags: bash, url, wget

I want to import several number of files into my server using `wget` , the 492 files are here:
https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?study=ERP001736

so I want to copy the URL of all files in "File Name" column to save them into a file and import them with `wget`.

So how can I copy all those URLs from that column ?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I suggest to start there: `man wget`

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged `bash`, this should work.

`wget -O-` is used to output the data to the standard output, where it's greppable. (`curl` would do that by default.)

`grep -oE` is used to capture the URLs (which happily are in a regular enough format that a simple regexp works).

Then, `wget -i` is used to read URLs from the file generated. You might wish to add `-nc` or other suitable partial-fetch flags; those files are pretty hefty.

```
wget -O- https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?study=ERP001736 | grep -oE 'http://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/[^"]+' > urls.txt
wget -i urls.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using a more specific and robust implementation...
*but*, in the case you are against a wall and in a hurry -

```
$: curl -s https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?study=ERP001736 |
     sed -En '/href="http:\/\/.*clean.fastq.gz"/{s/^.*href="([^"]+)".*/\1/;p;}' |
       while read url; do wget "$url"; done
```

This is a quick and *dirty* rough first pass, but it will give you something to work with.

If you *aren't* in a screaming hurry, try writing something more robust and step-wise in perl or python.